# How to set label fonts / BackColor with Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet

Tags: vb.net, winforms, userform

I have continued to develop the program I am working on and was able to populate a DataGridView with my Excel Spreadsheet data successfully, all of this works perfectly (currently).
However one this I did notice, was that since adding `Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet` any line of code that changes the Font of my Label or the BackColor will not work, specifying the error for example with BackColor: `'FromArgb' is not a member of 'Color'` or for instance in terms of Font: `Value of type 'FontFamily' cannot be converted to OpenXmlElement'`.
Now from what I can gather, my `Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet` is simply for spreadsheet stuff, I do not entirely know though, like I said my DataGridView is working perfectly. However I have lost the BackColor and Font functionality. What I was attempting to achieve (and had done previously before `Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet` was added, however I need this line for my DataGridView to work properly) was when my mouse went over my "Add Data" or "Contact" label for example, the font would increase slightly creating a pop effect and the back colour would change to Cyan so that it would stand out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is shown below:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EMMA
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet

Public Class frmDDEF
    Private Sub LoadExcelDataToDataGridView()
        If Not bckLoader.IsBusy Then
            bckLoader.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub bckLoader_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bckLoader.DoWork
        Dim filePath As String = "*spreadsheet path*"

        ' Define the row where your data starts in the Excel file
        Dim startingRow As Integer = 1 ' Start from Row 1

        Try
            Using spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, False)
                Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart
                Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()
                Dim worksheet As SheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements(Of SheetData)().First()

                ' Clear existing data in the DataGridView
                DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() DataGridView1.Rows.Clear())

                Dim rows = worksheet.Elements(Of Row)().Skip(startingRow - 1)

                For Each row In rows
                    Dim values = row.Elements(Of Cell)().Take(5).Select(Function(cell, colIndex)
                                                                            Dim cellValue = GetCellValue(workbookPart, cell)
                                                                            If colIndex = 1 Then ' Assuming Time column is at index 1
                                                                                Dim timeValue As Double
                                                                                If Double.TryParse(cellValue, timeValue) Then
                                                                                    Dim totalSeconds As Integer = CInt(timeValue * 24 * 60 * 60)
                                                                                    Dim hours As Integer = totalSeconds \ 3600
                                                                                    Dim minutes As Integer = (totalSeconds \ 60) Mod 60
                                                                                    Dim seconds As Integer = totalSeconds Mod 60
                                                                                    cellValue = $"{hours:D2}:{minutes:D2}:{seconds:D2}"
                                                                                End If
                                                                            End If
                                                                            Return cellValue
                                                                        End Function).ToList()

                    Dim hasData = values.Any(Function(value) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))

                    If hasData Then
                        DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() DataGridView1.Rows.Add(values.ToArray()))
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An error occurred: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCellValue(workbookPart As WorkbookPart, cell As Cell) As String
        Dim cellValue As String = cell.InnerText

        If cell.DataType IsNot Nothing AndAlso cell.DataType.Value = CellValues.SharedString Then
            Dim sharedStringTablePart As SharedStringTablePart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType(Of SharedStringTablePart).First()
            If sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements().Count > 0 Then
                Dim sharedStringItem As SharedStringItem = sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements().ElementAt(Integer.Parse(cellValue))
                cellValue = sharedStringItem.Text.Text
            End If
        ElseIf cell.DataType IsNot Nothing AndAlso cell.DataType.Value = CellValues.Date Then
            ' Handle Time format "hh:mm:ss"
            Dim excelTimeValue As Double
            If Double.TryParse(cellValue, excelTimeValue) Then
                Dim totalSeconds As Integer = CInt(excelTimeValue * 24 * 60 * 60)
                Dim hours As Integer = totalSeconds \ 3600
                Dim minutes As Integer = (totalSeconds \ 60) Mod 60
                Dim seconds As Integer = totalSeconds Mod 60
                cellValue = $"{hours:D2}:{minutes:D2}:{seconds:D2}"
            End If
        End If

        Return cellValue
    End Function

    Private Function ConvertToExcelColumnName(columnIndex As Integer) As String
        Dim dividend As Integer = columnIndex + 1
        Dim columnName As String = String.Empty

        While dividend > 0
            Dim modulo As Integer = (dividend - 1) Mod 26
            columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo) & columnName
            dividend = CInt((dividend - modulo) / 26)
        End While

        Return columnName
    End Function

    Private Sub tmrIconLoad_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrIconLoad.Tick
        Me.ShowIcon = False ' Disables icon once loaded
        tmrIconLoad.Enabled = False ' Disables timer
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmDDEF_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadExcelDataToDataGridView()
        tmrIconLoad.Enabled = True ' Triggers Timer to disable Icon once loaded
        grpPANELMENU.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26) ' Sets default colour of the Menu Panel
        grpPANELTOP.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26) ' Sets default colour of the Top Panel (has image on it anyway)
    End Sub

    ' CLICK CODE
    Private Sub lblAddData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblAddData.Click
        MessageBox.Show("This will allow you to Add Data")
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblPhoneLog_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblPhoneLog.Click
        MessageBox.Show("This will allow you to view the Phone Logs")
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblContact_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblContact.Click
        frmContact.LoadForm("loading")
    End Sub

    ' HIGHLIGHT CODE

    Private Sub lblAddData_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lblAddData.MouseMove
        lblAddData.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(3, 182, 252) ' Changes the Add Data Label to Cyan Highlight on the Menu Panel
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblPhoneLog_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lblPhoneLog.MouseMove
        ' lblPhoneLog.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(3, 182, 252) ' Changes the Phone Log Label to Cyan Highlight on the Menu Panel
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblContact_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lblContact.MouseMove
        '  lblContact.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(3, 182, 252) ' Changes the Contact Label to Cyan Highlight on the Menu Panel
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmDDEF_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
        ' lblAddData.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26) ' Removes the Cyan Highlight from the Add Data Label when the mouse goes over the Form
        'lblPhoneLog.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26) ' Removes the Cyan Highlight from the Phone Log Label when the mouse goes over the Form
        ' lblContact.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26) ' Removes the Cyan Highlight from the Contact Label when the mouse goes over the Form
    End Sub

    Private Sub grpPANELMENU_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles grpPANELMENU.MouseMove
        ' lblAddData.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26) ' Removes the Cyan Highlight from the Add Data Label when the mouse goes over the Panel Menu
        ' lblPhoneLog.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26) ' Removes the Cyan Highlight from the Phone Log Label when the mouse goes over the Panel Menu
        ' lblContact.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26) ' Removes the Cyan Highlight from the Contact Label when the mouse goes over the Panel Menu
    End Sub

    ' SELECTED LABEL EFFECT

    Private Sub lblAddData_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblAddData.MouseEnter
        lblAddData.Font = New Font(lblAddData.Font.FontFamily, lblAddData.Font.Size + 2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblAddData_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblAddData.MouseLeave
        ' lblAddData.Font = New Font(lblAddData.Font.FontFamily, lblAddData.Font.Size - 2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblPhoneLog_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblPhoneLog.MouseEnter
        ' lblPhoneLog.Font = New Font(lblPhoneLog.Font.FontFamily, lblPhoneLog.Font.Size + 2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblPhoneLog_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblPhoneLog.MouseLeave
        '  lblPhoneLog.Font = New Font(lblPhoneLog.Font.FontFamily, lblPhoneLog.Font.Size - 2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblContact_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblContact.MouseEnter
        '  lblContact.Font = New Font(lblContact.Font.FontFamily, lblContact.Font.Size + 2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblContact_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblContact.MouseLeave
        '  lblContact.Font = New Font(lblContact.Font.FontFamily, lblContact.Font.Size - 2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I commented out the sections of the code that wasn't working to stop the errors so I could still work on the project. These fixes aren't crucial but would be really nice to have :)

Comment: You say, "I need this line for my DataGridView to work properly".  Do you know why?  Do you need extension methods from the namespace?  Are you relying on accessing its members without namespace qualification?  If it's the former, I think you're stuck because you're relying on conflicting type definitions between two different namespaces, and you need both to be in the global namespace to access the extension methods.

Comment: But it doesn't look like either of the issues you identified actually involve an extension method.  `FromRGB` I think is just a normal shared method, and the other issue is with a type that you used to be able to use without qualification.  You can fix both by using the full namespace qualification for the framework type, e.g. use `System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRGB` to get `FromRGB` to work.

Comment: Honestly Craig, no I do not know why, I am new to VB.net and trying to learn, have some fun with it and see what I am able to do and accomplish. I have now changed my `Color.FromArgb` to `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb` and this seems to have worked perfectly.

Comment: Right, `System.Drawing` is the better source.  I'm not sure why that didn't come up when I searched the help docs.

Comment: I have no idea, I was stuck with the problem and was trying to find a solution but because of the Import causing the problem (reason I say this is because originally without that line it worked fine) and my lack of knowledge it was hard to find, so thought I would at least post here for advice and then when i found the solution (or at least a solution) post it in case others need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing research and a bunch of testing, `Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet` is the problem, however a work around is instead of using `Color.FromArgb` use `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb` due to a clash with the Xml. The same can be used with font, instead of `New Font` use `System.Drawing.Font`.

Examples shown below:

```
Private Sub lblAddData_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lblAddData.MouseMove
  lblAddData.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(3, 182, 252) ' Changes the Add Data Label to Cyan Highlight on the Menu Panel
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub lblAddData_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblAddData.MouseEnter
  lblAddData.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(lblAddData.Font.FontFamily, lblAddData.Font.Size + 2)
End Sub
```